# What is the simplest way to get results for last time specific month occurred in spark sql?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a month as an input and need to generate sql query that will get results for that month last occurrence - so previous or current year depending on the month - but I want it to be as human readable as possible. Tried this but it wont work as you can't use CASE that way:

```
WHERE month(DateF) = 11
AND year(DateF) = (
CASE WHEN 11 > month(CURRENT_DATE) 
THEN year(CURRENT_DATE)-1
ELSE year(CURRENT_DATE)
)
```

Comment: Can you give more details of your input and the output you want ? I have trouble to understand the all thing

Comment: input for ex "5", output data for last may

Comment: The complication here it that the year in the filter will be different depending if the month already passed this year or not - so I can't just always use current year every time

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Spark SQL in-built functions to work with date and time. These functions give capability to work with different dates, in different formats.

Refer: https://www.obstkel.com/spark-sql-date-functions

Comment: I know but none of them seems to do that - if I'm missing something please point me to the specifics

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that by using current_date and a day column (if you have it):

```
WHERE month(dateF) = X AND day >=  date_add(current_date(), -365)
```

Will this be possible for you ?